# Convert c# Keys to string

Tags: c#, keycode

I make a finger progamming in C#, and i wana when a user input to `textbox1`, this is display is `textbox2`. I don't know convert Keys to string, ex: `Keys.space`, `Keys.Back`... and `shirt + symbol` -> upper.

Comment: You probably won't need to convert keys, just copy the string. Anyways, show your attempt at solving the problem!

Comment: You may be looking for key down or preview key down.  Sorry for you poor English but this is very unclear.

Comment: wana in Swahili means kids. Could you reformat the question?

Comment: You can do it as per the question this is a duplicate of, but for the end result copying the text itself would be much easier.

Comment: thank you for help me! i will try your help.

Comment: Thank dude! i finished my app. Copy string is good idea. And it look like that: http://i64.tinypic.com/2d8nhwy.png